# MS Visual Studio 2008 + SSE + x64 + O2 incorrect results

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, sse

I wrote simple raytracer using MS VS 2008 (SP1) and SSE intrinsics. When I turn O2 optimization (for x86 platform) it speeds up 3 times. Obviously I would like to use it for x64 too. Unfortunately for x64 it causes some strange problems. I narrowed it to small piece of code.

Let's take folowing ray:

```
__m128 ray = _mm_set_ps( 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0 );
```

I want to normalize it and calculate [ 1/abs(x), 1/abs(y), 1/abs(z), 0 ]. Using x64 version without O2 optimization I get correct results:

```
Normalized abs: [ 0.57735, 0.57735, 0.57735, 0 ]
Result 1/v:     [ 1.73205, 1.73205, 1.73205, 0 ]
```

Using O2 I get:

```
Normalized abs: [ 0.57735, 0.57735, 0.57735, 0 ]
Result 1/v:     [ 1.73205, 1.73205, 0, 0 ]
```

Different changes to project settings cause this problem to disappear or appear again. For example "Enable link-time code generation (/GL)" helps in this example, but not in the whole program. As you can see this is really strange. Is O2 for x64 broken or my code uses some forbidden SSE constructs ? Here is the example:

RayInfo.h

```
#pragma once

#include <smmintrin.h>

class RayInfo
{
    public:

        RayInfo( const __m128 & ray );

        __m128i m_RayDir;
        __m128 m_Ray;
        __m128 m_RayNotZeroMask;
        __m128 m_RayPosMask;
        __m128 m_RayNegMask;
        __m128 m_AbsRay;
        __m128 m_One_AbsRay;
};
```

RayInfo.cpp

```
#include "RayInfo.h"

const __m128 onePosF = _mm_set_ps( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
const __m128 oneNegF = _mm_set_ps( 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0 );
const __m128 zeroF = _mm_setzero_ps();
const __m128 aaa = _mm_set_ps1( 123.0 );
const __m128 bbb = _mm_set_ps1( 456.0 );

__m128 normalized( const __m128 & v )
{
    // a0 = xx + yy + zz + ww
    __m128 dotProduct = _mm_dp_ps( v, v, 0xF1 );
    float tmp;
    _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT( tmp, dotProduct, 0 );
    if ( tmp != 0.0f )
    {
        dotProduct = _mm_sqrt_ss( dotProduct );
        _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT( tmp, dotProduct, 0 );
        return _mm_div_ps( v, _mm_set_ps1( tmp ) );
    }
    else return _mm_setzero_ps();
}

RayInfo::RayInfo( const __m128 & ray )
{
    m_Ray = normalized( ray );
    m_RayNotZeroMask = _mm_cmpneq_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );
    m_RayPosMask = _mm_cmpgt_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );
    m_RayNegMask = _mm_cmplt_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );
    m_RayDir = _mm_castps_si128( _mm_blendv_ps( zeroF, _mm_blendv_ps( aaa, bbb, m_RayPosMask ), m_RayNotZeroMask ) );
    m_AbsRay = _mm_andnot_ps( _mm_set_ps1( -0.0f ), m_Ray );
    m_One_AbsRay = _mm_blendv_ps( zeroF, _mm_div_ps( onePosF, m_AbsRay ), m_RayNotZeroMask );
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "RayInfo.h"

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    __m128 ray = _mm_set_ps( 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0 );
    RayInfo ri( ray );

    float result[ 4 ];
    _mm_store_ps( result, ri.m_AbsRay );
    std::cout << "Normalized abs: [ " << result[ 0 ] << ", " << result[ 1 ] << ", " << result[ 2 ] << ", " << result[ 3 ] << " ] " << std::endl;
    _mm_store_ps( result, ri.m_One_AbsRay );
    std::cout << "Result 1/v:     [ " << result[ 0 ] << ", " << result[ 1 ] << ", " << result[ 2 ] << ", " << result[ 3 ] << " ] " << std::endl;
}
```

**Edit:**

Assembly output optimized with O2:

```
; 27   :    m_RayNotZeroMask = _mm_cmpneq_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );

movaps  xmm4, XMMWORD PTR zeroF

; 28   :    m_RayPosMask = _mm_cmpgt_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );
; 29   :    m_RayNegMask = _mm_cmplt_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );
; 30   :    m_RayDir = _mm_castps_si128( _mm_blendv_ps( zeroF, _mm_blendv_ps( neg, pos, m_RayPosMask ), m_RayNotZeroMask ) );   

movaps  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR neg
movaps  xmm0, xmm5

; 31   :    m_AbsRay = _mm_andnot_ps( _mm_set_ps1( -0.0f ), m_Ray );    
; 32   :    m_One_AbsRay = _mm_blendv_ps( zeroF, _mm_div_ps( onePosF, m_AbsRay ), m_RayNotZeroMask );   
; 33   : }

mov rax, rcx
cmpltps xmm0, xmm4
movaps  xmm1, xmm4
movaps  xmm3, xmm4
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+16], xmm5
cmpltps xmm1, xmm5
cmpneqps xmm3, xmm5
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+48], xmm1
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+32], xmm3
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+64], xmm0
blendvps xmm2, XMMWORD PTR pos, xmm1
movaps  xmm1, xmm4
blendvps xmm1, xmm2, xmm3
movss   xmm2, DWORD PTR __real@80000000
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rcx], xmm1
movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR onePosF
shufps  xmm2, xmm2, 0
andnps  xmm2, xmm5
divps   xmm1, xmm2
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+80], xmm2
blendvps xmm4, xmm1, xmm3
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+96], xmm4
add rsp, 24
ret 0
```

Assembly output without O2:

```
; 27   :    m_RayNotZeroMask = _mm_cmpneq_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );

mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+16]
cmpneqps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR zeroF
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6429[rsp], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6429[rsp]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax+32], xmm0

; 28   :    m_RayPosMask = _mm_cmpgt_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );

mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR zeroF
cmpltps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+16]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6430[rsp], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6430[rsp]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax+48], xmm0

; 29   :    m_RayNegMask = _mm_cmplt_ps( m_Ray, zeroF );

mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+16]
cmpltps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR zeroF
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6431[rsp], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6431[rsp]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax+64], xmm0

; 30   :    m_RayDir = _mm_castps_si128( _mm_blendv_ps( zeroF, _mm_blendv_ps( neg, pos, m_RayPosMask ), m_RayNotZeroMask ) );   

mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+48]
movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR neg
blendvps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR pos, xmm0
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6432[rsp], xmm1
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+32]
movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR zeroF
blendvps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR $T6432[rsp], xmm0
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6433[rsp], xmm1
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6433[rsp]
movdqa  XMMWORD PTR $T6434[rsp], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6434[rsp]
movdqa  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0

; 31   :    m_AbsRay = _mm_andnot_ps( _mm_set_ps1( -0.0f ), m_Ray );    

movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@80000000
shufps  xmm0, xmm0, 0
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6435[rsp], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6435[rsp]
andnps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+16]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6436[rsp], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6436[rsp]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax+80], xmm0

; 32   :    m_One_AbsRay = _mm_blendv_ps( zeroF, _mm_div_ps( onePosF, m_AbsRay ), m_RayNotZeroMask );   

mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR onePosF
divps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+80]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6437[rsp], xmm0
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+32]
movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR zeroF
blendvps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR $T6437[rsp], xmm0
movaps  XMMWORD PTR $T6438[rsp], xmm1
mov rax, QWORD PTR this$[rsp]
movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR $T6438[rsp]
movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rax+96], xmm0
mov rcx, QWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[rsp]
xor rcx, rsp
call    __security_check_cookie
add rsp, 248                ; 000000f8H
ret 0
```

**Edit:**

Link to project:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz554SfOcR3AS3QxZzJrZEZJelE/edit

Comment: Have you tried VS 2010/2012? VS2008 is known to have bugs with certain SSE intrinsics.

Comment: I had to fix your code, result requires `__declspec(align(16))`.  And did not repro the problem on VS2008 SP1.

Comment: I haven't tried any other VS. And indeed I forgot about alignment, but it doesn't help :(. Could you try turning of /GL ?

Comment: I'm sure that it will be much easier to track down if you post the assembly output.

Comment: Reduce your code to a single source file, post the complete set of options you are passing to the compiler on the command line, and the complete version of the compiler.  Also, you should upgrade to Visual C++ 2012.  Visual C++ 2008 is ancient.

Comment: A couple years back, I ran into an bug with VS2008 involving the SSE4.1 extract and insert intrinsics. I submitted a bug report to MS and they confirmed it and that it had been fixed for VS2010. I'm willing to bet this might be the same bug since you're using `_MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT`.

Comment: When I reduce my code to a single file, the problem disappears :/.

Comment: When I remove normalization (and usage of _MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT), problem changes but results are still wrong :/.

Comment: I tried VS 2012 Express and there is no problem with that compiler. Results are correct. Unfortunately it does not support plugins and I need QT plugin, so I can not use it with my project.

Comment: @Mikosz: Visual Studio 2012 absolutely supports plugins.

Comment: @SecurityMatt Free VS 2012 Express version unfortunately does not. I could buy VS 2012 Profesional, but "download only via microsoft store" costs 499$ in US, and about 800$ in my country, which is a bit strange and expensive (for a hobby). It is so sad that there is no Standard version anymore.